# Couldn't airplanes have more emergency exits?

Tags: safety, emergency, passenger

Being near an emergency exit improves considerably the survival chances after an accident. Why not put one exit at every 5 rows?

Comment: Exits increase the price of the ticket?

Comment: The same reason why there aren't parachutes available for each passenger separately in an aircraft.

Answer (score 15):

Money.

Doors cost (and weight) a *lot* more than plain aluminum panels. And the exit row on larger planes usually consumes one row of seats. So lets say we are on a 767 and take out every 6th outer row, that's 5 extra exit rows and 20 fewer paying seats, or $6,000 less per flight which quickly adds up to nearly the cost of the aircraft itself over its service life. And that's quite a lot of money for something that will very likely never be used. Remember that exit doors only help if the plane crash-lands in a mostly upright position. Severe crashes often add large exits by splitting the fuselage open, and lawn-dart mode accidents don't leave too many survivors.

The flying public has indicated that they are very interested in ticket price, but somewhat less interested in the safety factor. The current accident rates appear to be acceptable to those paying for the service.

Comment: "Lawn dart mode". Excellent!

Comment: It's also possible that more emergency exits will mean *more* deaths.  Adding more exits will reduce the number of passengers each plane can carry, meaning more flights and more non-survivable crashes, but fewer crashes where passengers can't exit in time.  It's unclear which very rare effect will be the deciding factor in the total number of passenger fatalities.

Comment: `The flying public has indicated that they are very interested in ticket price, but somewhat less interested in the safety factor.` So if I'm getting a deal on the fare, I don't care about *getting* to my destination? Ironically, that **is** true.

Comment: Btw Paul, you are contributing very nice contents here. Why haven't you registered?

Comment: @Farhan simply because the process is bothersome.

Comment: Also more doors means more door maintenance means more maintenance costs.